# How to remove the time delay for 'onmessage'

Tags: javascript, html, worker

The main goal is to make the fastest (> 200fps) message exchange of the main thread with the worker, regardless of whether the tab is active or not.

example:

Worker code:

```
onmessage = function(rawMsg) {
    var msg = rawMsg.data;

    msg.state = "worker-THREAD:setInterval=>main-THREAD:onmessage=>worker-THREAD:onmessage";
    msg.times.push( performance.now() );

    postMessage(msg);
}

var sequenceNum = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    var msg = {state:"", times: [], sequenceNum: sequenceNum++};

    msg.state = "worker-THREAD:setInterval";
    msg.times.push( performance.now() );

    postMessage(msg);
}, 100);
```

Main thread code:

```
var worker = new Worker( 'js/test-worker.js' );

worker.onmessage = function(rawMsg) {
    var msg = rawMsg.data;

    switch( msg.state ) {
        case "worker-THREAD:setInterval":
            msg.state = "worker-THREAD:setInterval=>main:thread:onmessage";
            msg.times.push( performance.now() );

            worker.postMessage(msg);
            break;

        case "worker-THREAD:setInterval=>main-THREAD:onmessage=>worker-THREAD:onmessage":
            show(msg);
            break;
    }
}

var lastSequenceNum = 0;
function show(msg) {
    msg.times = msg.times.map(function(val) { return val / 1e3 });

    if ( lastSequenceNum++ !== msg.sequenceNum ) {
        alert("error sequence");
    }

    var ping = msg.times[2] - msg.times[0];

    var isBad = ( ping > 0.01 );

    var fx = 3;

    var times = msg.times.map(function(val) { return val.toFixed(fx) });

    console.log('#' + msg.sequenceNum + ' [ ' + times.join(', ') + ' ] ' + ping.toFixed(fx) + (isBad?' BAD!!!': ''));
}
```

```js
  var worker_Code = `
    onmessage = function(rawMsg) {
      var msg = rawMsg.data;

      msg.state = "worker-THREAD:setInterval=>main-THREAD:onmessage=>worker-THREAD:onmessage";
      msg.times.push( performance.now() );

      postMessage(msg);
    }

    var sequenceNum = 0;

    setInterval(function() {
      var msg = {state:"", times: [], sequenceNum: sequenceNum++};

      msg.state = "worker-THREAD:setInterval";
      msg.times.push( performance.now() );

      postMessage(msg);
    }, 100);
  `;

  var worker = new Worker( window.URL.createObjectURL( new Blob( [worker_Code] ) ) );

 worker.onmessage = function(rawMsg) {
  var msg = rawMsg.data;

  switch( msg.state ) {
   case "worker-THREAD:setInterval":
    msg.state = "worker-THREAD:setInterval=>main:thread:onmessage";
    msg.times.push( performance.now() );

    worker.postMessage(msg);
    break;

   case "worker-THREAD:setInterval=>main-THREAD:onmessage=>worker-THREAD:onmessage":
    show(msg);
    break;
  }
 }

 var lastSequenceNum = 0;
 function show(msg) {
  msg.times = msg.times.map(function(val) { return val / 1e3 });

  if ( lastSequenceNum++ !== msg.sequenceNum ) {
   alert("error sequence");
  }

  var ping = msg.times[2] - msg.times[0];

  var isBad = ( ping > 0.01 );

  var fx = 3;

  var times = msg.times.map(function(val) { return val.toFixed(fx) });

  console.log('#' + msg.sequenceNum + ' [ ' + times.join(', ') + ' ] ' + ping.toFixed(fx) + (isBad?' BAD!!!': ''));
 }
```

On jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/03pfwmt9/

If the tab is not active, messages accumulate and once in one sec all come to 'onmessage'.
How can I fix this?